# Prove that $det(A)= a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 $

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that:

$ det(A)=
\begin{vmatrix}
a_n&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
a_{n-1}&x&-1&\cdots&0\\
\vdots&0&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
a_1&\vdots&\ddots&x&-1\\
a_0&0&\cdots&0&x
\end{vmatrix}
= a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0 $

I just couldn’t see how to manipulate the matrix.

Comment: Try expanding the determinant with the first column.

Comment: Related: [the companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

Comment: Expanding with respect to the first *row* is much easier to do.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** Denote the matrix $A$  by $A_n$. Try prove  that $\det A_n=a_n x^n+\det A_{n-1}.$